# MySQL user-defined comparator

Tags: mysql, join, comparator

Is it possible to define a special comparator in MySQL for indexing?

Say I have two keys, `A.Zeb*ra.O` and `R.Zebra.Z`. I have them written this way give some extra information to the user, but for equality purposes I can strip out the ends and remove the extra `*`. In Java I could do this by implementing the `Comparator` interface. Is there a similar idea for MySQL?

Would I be better off just creating an extra join table like

```
A.Zeb*ra.O   1
R.Zebra.Z    1
L.Horse.P    2
```

To specify that two specific strings are equal, and keep this table up to date when the other table changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new collation, which is similar to creating a comparator but only for strings. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/adding-collation.html

Answer (score 1):

You can't define a comparator like in Java, etc. A collation may work, but I have no experience with those. Off the top of my head, here are some alternatives:

1. Write a user-defined function to do the comparison. This would be relatively slow and  impossible to optimize.
2. Store a canonical sort value for each row. You could calculate its value with a trigger. For example, your table would look like this.

   ```
   Thingie     CanonicalThingie
   ----------- ----------------
   A.Zeb*ra.O  Zebra
   R.Zebra.Z   Zebra
   L.Horse.P   Horse
   ```
3. Reconsider your design. If the `A.Zeb*ra.0` value means three or four things, it probably needs to be split into three or four columns. You're probably facing more challenges than just sorting it.